# Magento 2 add parent ID as class on children in Topmenu

Tags: magento2, topmenu

I made a theme in magento 2.2 based on Luma, and I have to make a design for the Topmenu like in the picture below.
[image]

This is the category structure in backend.

[image]

I already made a plugin that displays only the children in the menu but how can I add the parents ID as a class on the children so I can make different design for categories in "Iarna" (Winter) and different design for "Vara" (Summer).

Or what is the recommended way to achieve that design.

This is the code from plugin.

```
class Topmenu
{
protected $storeManager;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
)
{
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

public function beforeGetHtml(
    \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject,
    $outermostClass = '',
    $childrenWrapClass = '',
    $limit = 0
) {
    $storeIds = [1];//replace with the id of your store.
    $currentStoreId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    if (in_array($currentStoreId, $storeIds)) {
        $menu = $subject->getMenu();
        $newMenuItems = [];
        $firstLevel = $menu->getChildren();

        foreach ($firstLevel as $menuItem) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuItem */
            //check if menu is a category
            if (substr($menuItem->getId(), 0, strlen('category-node-')) == 'category-node-') {
                //get all child nodes (second level) and save them in an array
                $subItems = $menuItem->getChildren();
                foreach ($subItems as $subItem) {
                    $newMenuItems[] = $subItem;
                }

            } else { //if menu item is not a category, leave it in place
                $newMenuItems[] = $menuItem;
            }
        }
        //remove all menu items
        foreach ($firstLevel as $childNode) {
            $menu->removeChild($childNode);
        }
        //put new menu items back;
        foreach ($newMenuItems as $newMenuItem) {
            $menu->addChild($newMenuItem);
        }
    }
  }
}
```